# How to write an array that stores interrupt codes?

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I'm having difficulty with x86 assembly. (I'm programming on Emu8086 for Windows / 64.)
I would like to know how to write on the screen this matrix with its respective interruptions

```
 TETRA_T2   DB  32, 32, 32,32
               DB  32, 219,32,32
               DB  32, 219,219,32 
               DB  32, 219,32,32
```

I can't put '$' at the end of the array and use for exemple:

```
 mov DX, offset VETOR_TELA 



            mov ah,9H
            int 21h
```

It will conflict with another matrix that I wrote this way.

Does anyone know of any way to write this matrix?

Comment: Try int 21/AH=40 on file descriptor 1.

Comment: You mean "print?  Loop over it and print each integer separately.  [Displaying numbers with DOS](//stackoverflow.com/q/45904075).  It's obviously not a string of ASCII characters so you don't want to copy those bytes directly as text.  Or do you want to do the equivalent of C `fwrite()` on this binary data like fuz suggested?

Comment: Hi Petter, these numbers are actually the ascii numbers that I will have to write on the screen. In this case 32 is a blank space ... I wonder if it would have a more practical way than having to write character by character

Comment: @YODA Not really.  You could assemble the entire string in memory in advance and then write it out at once, but the effort is roughly the same.

Comment: exemple please?